# Can Black draw by perpetual check?

Tags: analysis, draw, check

In this position, from the game [Carlsen-Radjabov](https://www.chessgames.com/perl/chessgame?gid=1599963), it
is White to move. Is it possible to get rid of the checks?

```
[Title "Carlsen-Radjabov, World Blitz Championship, Moscow Russia, 11/18/2010"]
[FEN "7B/5p1k/6p1/3P2Kp/2n1P3/5P2/6q1/Q4N2 w - - 0 1"]
```

Answer (score 2):

> Can Black draw by perpetual checks?

Only if white blunders, doesn't see Kf6 and instead plays Kh4. Yes, Kf6 allows black to capture the bishop on h8 but that leads to a swift mate. Blacks best try is to keep taking pawns and checking but eventually he has to exchange queens to avoid mate and White still has one pawn left plus the extra piece to give him the win.

```
[title "Carlsen-Radjabov 2010 Blitz"]
[fen "7B/5p1k/6p1/3P2Kp/2n1P3/5P2/6q1/Q4N2 w - - 0 1"]

1. Kf6 Qxf3+ (1...Kxh8 2. Kxf7+ Qb2 3. Qa8+ Kh7 4. Qg8+ Kh6 5. Qxg6#) 2. Ke7 Qxe4+ 3. Kf8 Kh6 4. Bg7+ Kh7 (4...Kg5 5. Qc1+ Kg4 6. Qxc4 Qxc4 7. Ne3+) 5. Qc1 g5 6. Qxg5 Qg6 7. Qxg6 fxg6 8. Ne3
```